# Linker cannot find VirtualAllocFromApp

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2019

A dynamic library i'm linking to is referencing VirtualAllocFromApp so i tried to link with Kernel32.lib as mentioned in [VirtualAllocFromApp function (msdn)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualallocfromapp) but the linker still insists that it cannot find it:

```
unresolved external symbol __imp_VirtualAllocFromApp referenced in function ...
```

I searched all Kernel32.lib's i've got using

```
C:\>for /f "usebackq delims=|" %f in (`dir Kernel32.lib /s/b`) do echo %f && dumpbin /exports "%f" | findstr VirtualAllocFromApp
```

but there's none exporting VirtualAllocFromApp.

Obviously i'm doing something completely wrong but i don't know what that could be.

The library calling that function basically just distinguishes between the old-school VirtualAlloc and the new ...FromApp with

```
#if (_MSC_VER <= 1900)
        VirtualAlloc(...);
#else
        VirtualAllocFromApp(...);
#endif
```

I can proxy it myself to VirtualAlloc which will warn about

```
warning C4273: 'VirtualAllocFromApp': inconsistent dll linkage
```

but work around that otherwise but this seems to be plain wrong. What am i missing here?

Comment: What version of Windows are you on ?   _"...Minimum supported client Windows 10..."_ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualallocfromapp

Comment: Sounds like you have an out-of-date Windows SDK installed. Have you tried updating? Otherwise, you could try simply implementing `VirtualAllocFromApp()` in your own code, and have it internally load `VirtualAllocFromApp()` dynamically from `kernel32.dll`.

Comment: @RichardCritten I'm on win10 20H2

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm using VS2019 16.8.4 and installed most of the win sdks. Project setting is set to use the latest one. VS installer doesn't show a newer one than 10.0.19041.0. With the for...dumpbin above i searched through all at least 31 different kernel32.lib (most in C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib) and none contained that export, including the newest win10 sdk which makes me think that i'm missing something obvious and crucial.

Comment: You want windowsapp.lib, the umbrella library for apps (which is what the "FromApp" suffix is hinting at). I'll see what I can to do fix the documentation.

Comment: @RaymondChen Works perfectly. Thank you very much!